# DataTables - Image dissappears in TH in responsive mode

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, datatables

I am using the plugin "DataTables" in my website, and I want to put an image inside a TH in a table, but this image dissappears when I use the responsive mode!

Here is an example:
http://live.datatables.net/qikocosi/1/edit

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: while using responsive the datatables change into a list <ul><li></li></ul> this could be the reason for the image disappearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer:

You have to modify one simple line on dataTables.responsive.js

Change:

```
var title = header.text();
```

For:

```
var title = header.html();
```

Thanks AAB and Ivan Jocovic for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an officially supported way to do it, but you might try this workaround:

It seems that switching to responsive mode is removing html from header cells (including your `img` tag), so you might want to use some CSS to achieve this:

```
li[data-dtr-index="1"] span.dtr-title{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/iKWdGjP.png?1");
  color: transparent;
}
```

As this js library is adding `:` char automatically, I am using `color: transparent;` to hide it. Therefore, if you want to include some text beside your image, remove this part of CSS.

Also, as empty `span` will not show any `background-image`, I have added `&nbsp;` to your html:

```
<th class="tablet">&nbsp;<img src="http://i.imgur.com/iKWdGjP.png?1"></th>
```

Example is here:
http://live.datatables.net/nijejoye/1/edit